# The general Ramanujan–Nagell equation $x^2+D=y^n$

Tags: diophantine-equations

It is known that the general  Ramanujan–Nagell equation $x^2+D=y^n$
Have no solution for $ D<100 $ see the table in the paper

CLASSICAL AND MODULAR APPROACHES TO
EXPONENTIAL DIOPHANTINE EQUATIONS
II. THE LEBESGUE–NAGELL EQUATION by
YANN BUGEAUD, MAURICE MIGNOTTE, SAMIR SIKSEK

My question is there some work for the case when $D>100$?

Comment: alright, part I was the Annals, year 2006. part II is in Compositio Math, same year

Comment: different title, more authors, in 2008.

Comment: @will Jagy can you give please title of the article

Comment: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ant/1513797332

Comment: Title says $x^n+D=y^n$, body says $x^2+D=y^n$. Which is it?